# Confusion Matrix: ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of unknown and multiclass targets

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I have a long script, but the key point is here:

```
result = confusion_matrix(y_test, ypred)
```

where `y_test` is

```
    >>> y_test
    ZFFYZTN     3
    ZDDKDTY     0
    ZTYKTYKD    0
    ZYNDQNDK    1
    ZYZQNKQN    3
               ..
    ZYMDDTM     3
    ZYLNYFLM    0
    ZTNTKDY     0
    ZYYLZNKM    3
    ZYZMQTZT    0

Name: BT, Length: 91, dtype: object
```

and the values are

```
>>> y_test.values
array([3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0,
       1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2,
       0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0,
       0, 3, 0], dtype=object)
```

and `ypred` is

```
>>> ypred
array([3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0,
       1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2,
       0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0,
       0, 3, 0])
```

gives

```
    raise ValueError("Classification metrics can't handle a mix of {0} "
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of unknown and multiclass targets
```

The confusing part is that I don't see *any* unknown targets.

so I checked out [ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of unknown and binary targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018742/valueerror-classification-metrics-cant-handle-a-mix-of-unknown-and-binary-targ) but the solution there doesn't apply in my case, because all values are integers.

I've also checked [Skitlearn MLPClassifier ValueError: Can't handle mix of multiclass and multilabel-indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665253/skitlearn-mlpclassifier-valueerror-cant-handle-mix-of-multiclass-and-multilabe) but there aren't any encodings in my data.

What can I do to get the confusion matrix and avoid these errors?

Comment: did you try `result = confusion_matrix(y_test.values, ypred)`? It seems that your `y_test` contains more than only classes

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work

Comment: It would help if you provided more info. My guess is that y_test is the problem. What is its shape? There are multiple columns, this is why the error says multiclass targets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is due to confusing types.

The solution is to cast y_test values as a list to `confusion_matrix`:

```
result = confusion_matrix(list(y_test.values), ypred)
```